# Python expected one argument, found three, what is the proper syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, arguments, string-formatting

For example...

```
day=1

question=int(input("How many cookies did you eat on day number", day, " ?"))
```

and then in a loop, I've got `day=day+1` so, when it repeats, it asks about day 1, 2, 3...

I understand that this is not the correct syntax, obviously, because Python keeps refusing it saying that it expected one argument and got three. How do I set it up?

Comment: you are passing three arguments(see,) in `input()` function . It should be  a single string. So make a single string and pass that, as Ashwini suggesting in his answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use string formatting:

```
input("How many cookies did you eat on day number {}?".format(day))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you put , (comma). You have to use + for concatanate.
For example:

```
question = int(input("How many cookies did you eat on day number"+ str(day)+ " ?"))
```

Comment: While this will accomplish OP's goal, `.format()` is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for share your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

The input method only takes one argument (i.e. input()). If you want to insert a variable into the prompt, instead of commas, use '+' to concatenate the information, for example:

```
question = int(input("How many cookies did you eat on day number " + str(day) + "?")
```